# Unable to initalize spark object in a Python class

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I created sparkSession object in `delta_interface_logids.py` file as shown below:

```
from loader.LoadRunner import LoadRunner
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


def get_data(spark):
    do_something_with_spark
    return something


if __name__ == "__main__":
    max_interface_log_id_dict = {}
    sparkConf = SparkConf().setAppName("DummyAP").set("spark.jars", "/home/usrname/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar ")
    spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=sparkConf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    log_data = get_data(spark)
    load = LoadRunner(spark)
```

I have the output of `get_data()` in a variable `log_data` & I am trying to implement a class in Python that takes `log_data` and does some operation. To do that, I created a class like below: 
[image]

But when I tried to use the features of spark object, I see that spark object is not initializd properly as I don't see the methods generated by sparkSession object: `spark` which I have initialized in `__init__` method which can be seen in the screenshot.

Is there any mistake I did here that I don't see the spark object's methods properly ?
How do I send and initialize the spark object properly to the class `LoadRunner` from the file: `delta_interface_logids.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the editor is unable to know which kind of object `spark` is while you are defining your class. Just because you named the class argument `spark`, it does not necessarily mean that your code is going to handle a `SparkSession` object.

This is an inherent "issue" (many quotes) of dynamic languages. Function arguments don't have types outside the runtime. When you are defining a class with your editor, you are definitely not in runtime.

### Extra

For anyone using Python >3.5, I strongly recommend using [type annotations](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/typing.html). These annotations help to improve code documentation and can be checked statically with tools such as [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

For example, in the code above, I would recommend something like this:

```
def __init__(self, spark: SparkSession):
    ...
```

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say but in such cases there is no gaurantee anywhere and in any file in a project that an IDE is going to identify what type of object I am using to generate its methods. So nothing wrong with the code ?

Comment: @Metadata, there is nothing wrong with your code so far.

Comment: @Metadata, I strongly recommend using type annotations if you are using Python >3.5.

Comment: This solved the issue, but if someone is using version less than 3.5, it looks like they have to trust their coding abilities and rely a bit less on IDEs.

Comment: Python 3.4 is way beyond its end of life. And Spark has very good [type annotations](https://github.com/zero323/pyspark-stubs) which could be used independent of version.